# how do I add two values to option value and seperate with with a comma javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select

I am trying to put two values in option value separating with comma using javascript but when I get the value from server it shows only the first value i.e course code

javascript Code

```
      options += "<option value="+element.course_code+","+element.course_id+">(" + element.course_code + ") " + element.name + "</options>";
      data.append('course_id', course_id);
```

Server

```
$myvalue = $request->get('course_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put quotes around the value so it is treated as one whole string

```
  options += "<option value='"+element.course_code+","+element.course_id+"'>(" + element.course_code + ") " + element.name + "</options>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following code instead by declaring the single string.

The code should look like:

```
options += "<option value="+element.course_code+','+element.course_id+">(" + element.course_code + ") " + element.name + "</options>";
```